# Can somebody explain this C++ typedef?

Tags: c++, typedef

I've just started working with C++ after not having worked with it for quite a while. While most of it makes sense, there are some bits that I'm finding a bit [confuddling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confuddle). For example, could somebody please explain what this line does:

```
typedef bool (OptionManager::* OptionHandler)(const ABString& value);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why somebody downvoted this...

Comment: It's without doubt a duplicate. Point is, we have as much problems finding identical questions as you did. (not my downvote BTW)

Comment: Glad to see I am not the only one who find the functions pointer syntax awkward... at the best of times!

Comment: @MSalters:  I don't downvote dupes myself, I vote to close.  However, I didn't find anything this is a dupe of.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It defines the type `OptionHandler` to be a pointer to a member function of the class `OptionManager`, and where this member function takes a parameter of type `const ABString&` and returns `bool`.

Answer (score 9):

```
typedef bool (OptionManager::* OptionHandler)(const ABString& value);
```

Let's start with:

```
OptionManager::* OptionHandler
```

This says that `::* OptionHandler` is a member function of the class `OptionManager`.
The `*` in front of `OptionHandler` says it's a pointer; this means `OptionHandler` is a pointer to a member function of a class `OptionManager`.

`(const ABString& value)` says that the member function will take a value of type `ABString` into a const reference.

`bool` says that the member function will return a boolean type.

`typedef` says that using "* OptionHandler" you can create many function pointers which can store that address of that function. For example:

```
OptionHandler fp[3];
```

`fp[0], fp[1], fp[2]` will store the addresses of functions whose semantics match with the above explanation.

Comment: Nice that you break the type into smaller pieces, but "`::* OptionHandler` is a member function": why not a plain member?  This is only detected when looking at the surroundings.

Answer (score 4):

this is a pointer to a member function of OptionManager that takes a const ABString refrence and returns a bool

Answer (score 2):

It is a typedef to a pointer to member function. Please check [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html).